# Adding .sql or .csv file to android app's sqLite database

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in this app I want to make an Sq-lite database that is available on online database(MySQL). Now I want to know how to import that file in AndroidStudio.Thanks.

Comment: You should come create your prepared database. Copy it into raw folder of Android project. In runtime copy this file into database directory. Than you can use your database in the app

Comment: @Vyacheslav database that we make through our code has .db as extension,would it fetch data from file having .sql extension.

Comment: check only the first bytes of the file.